# Как правильно разрешать *контекст* при использовании сервисов?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, autofac

```
public class Act
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Operation Operation {get;set;}
}

public class Operation
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Act Act {get;set;}
}

public class ActService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public ActService(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
    public void Delete(int actId)
    {
        var entity = _context.Set<Act>().Single(x => x.Id == actId);
        //бизнес логика удаления объекта
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges()
    }
}

public OperationService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly ActService _actService;

    public OperationService(DbContext context, ActService actSErvice)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._actService = actService;
    }

    public void Delete(int operationId)
    {
        var entity = _context.Set<Operation>().Include(x => x.Act)(x => x.Id == operationId);
        //бизнес логика удаления объекта
        using(var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                _actService.Delete(operation.Act.Id);
                _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В проекте используется [autofac](/questions/tagged/autofac) версии 4.6.1. Внедрение зависимостей происходит через конструктор.

Подскажите как правильно реализовать *разрешение* зависимостей что бы не было нарушение логики, что удалиться должно либо все либо ничего.

P.S.:
Справку на сайте читал, я предполагаю что `DbContext` должен внедряться как `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` а *сервис* как `.InstancePerRequest()`, но точной уверенности у меня нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы гарантировать одинаковость экземпляров DbContext, его нужно создавать с явным указанием времени жизни.

Это означает, что нельзя использовать варианты Instance Per Dependency (по очевидным причинам) и Instance Per Lifetime Scope (потому что Lifetime Scope может оказаться внезапно разным).

Допустимо использовать Single Instance, Instance Per Matching Lifetime Scope, Instance Per Request и Instance Per Owned (последние два - на самом деле то же самый Instance Per Matching Lifetime Scope).

Сами сервисы при этом могут создаваться с любым временем жизни которое не ниже времени жизни контекста (т.е. даже Instance Per Dependency ничего не порушит).

---

Если же есть желание гарантировать правильную работу независимо от настроек DI (хотя это странно) - придется изменить код.

Например, можно передавать DbContext как параметр метода:

```
public class ActService
{
    public void Delete(DbContext context, int actId)
    {
        var entity = context.Set<Act>().Single(x => x.Id == actId);
        //бизнес логика удаления объекта
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        // Save Changes не вызываем ибо незачем
    }
}
```

Или же можно воспользоваться транзакциями окружения (Ambient Transactions) если устраивает их цена (автоматическая эскалация до распределенной транзакции при случайном использовании нескольких контекстов):

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    // любые изменения которые делаются тут будут происходить в транзакции
    ts.Complete();
}
```